# Javascript and Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick, conditional-statements, toggle

I'm trying to create a checkbox which will alter the form action on click. I'm starting out by setting it to alert a message depending on whether it is checked or not but nothing is happening. Please help me!

JavaScript:

```
function toggleAction(){
var check = document.getElementById('checkb').checked;
   if (checked == "1"){
    alert("is checked");
   }else{
    alert("is not checked"); }
}
```

HTML:

```
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" id="checkb" onclick="toggleAction()">Add Another<br>
```

Comment: The name of your variable is `check` but you're checking the value of a variable named `checked` in the `if` statement, which does not exist in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main problem is that you named your variable `check` but then in your `if` statement looked for `checked`. Secondarily, note that `.checked` is a boolean value (`true` or `false`) but you are comparing it to the string "1". This happens to work, but is not recommended.

Try:

```
if (check) alert("is checked");
else       alert("is not checked");
```

Better than using `getElementById` explicitly in your handler, also, is to use the reference to the checkbox handling the event:

```
document.getElementById('checkb').onclick = toggleAction;
function toggleAction(){
  if (this.checked) alert('yes');
  else              alert('no');
}
```

Note in the above how I also assigned the event handler programmatically using JavaScript instead of using the `onclick="..."` HTML attribute. This is considered a "best practice"; you should not be writing JavaScript directly in your HTML.

Comment: +1 - if(x == 1) and if(x == "1") are two completely different conditions. The 1 is true, while "1" is a string.

Comment: @DavidHoude Yet note that in loosely-typed JavaScript `1=="1"` is `true`; you would need to use `1==="1"` if you did not want type coercion performed. (And, indeed, `true==1` and `true=="1"` are both also true.)

Comment: i originally had no quotes, but that didn't work. i only recently added them to see if it would change anything

Answer (score 1):

The line `if(checked == "1")` should be `if(check)`.